# Changing the value of val field

Tags: scala, immutability

Is it possible to change the value of `val` field?
If so, is that done only through constructors and not anywhere in the program? 
Using `val` means that the memory location can never be modified?
For example:
`val x = 5`
Can I again use `x` to point to a different location with different value?

Answer (score 11):

In short: **No, you cannot**. *This is the point of immutability*, ensuring that you can **always** be sure that the value stays the same.

This is why there's an option of immutables [**vals**] and mutables [**vars**] it's flexible and allows you to choose depending on your needs. Pick your choice and live with its rules.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a field to be mutable, you should declare it as `var` instead of `val`. If for some reason you cannot change a `val` to a `var` and still need to change its value, you can do this using reflection.

```
class ModifyVal {
  val x = 5
}

object ModifyVal {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val instance = new ModifyVal()
    println(instance.x) // 5
    // instance.x = 10 doesn't compile: Reassignment to val
    val fieldX = instance.getClass.getDeclaredField("x")
    fieldX.setAccessible(true)
    fieldX.setInt(instance, 10)
    println(instance.x) // 10
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it is evil. Since Scala runs on the JVM, there's no way to prevent this sort of mischief, but it goes against the fundamental design of the language. Any usage of `field.setAccessible(true)` in a Scala program just feels dirty.

Comment: I agree with you, but it might be necessary to change a val, e.g., when writing tests for legacy code. This would however be a sign that your code should be refacored.

Answer (score 3):

val is immutable.
If you wanna change the value, you should use var instead.

[Difference between val and var scala](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=difference%20var%20and%20var%20scala)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule (without resorting to contortions that warp the intent of the language), no you cannot modify a `val`, nor should you want to. Instead, if you wish to keep to a functional style of programming, consider making a copy of the containing instance, with a modified value for the `val` field. Case classes already help with this by providing a `copy` constructor to enable this sort of manipulation:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
  def birthday = copy(age = age + 1) // returns a new Person with the same name, but one year older
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***val***, roughly speaking, means ***constant*** (*final* in Java).

When declared, a **val** must be assigned to something, either a value

```
val name: String // compilation error
val name : String = "Hello"
```

or nothing (though nobody does this)

```
val name : String = _
```

After a val is assigned, it cannot be re-assigned.

Immutability is a useful characteristic that is strongly supported by Scala. This encourage writing code that is free of side-effect and thread-safe. This is why Scala is a good choice for scalable and concurrent applications.

A special kind of immutability in Scala is Future. Future is a write-once container – after a future has been completed, it is effectively immutable.